# Update a huge size text file using Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have around 300GB fulldata and daily I’ll get an update on this data around 10GB. Both files are in text format. I would like to update the fulldata based on updates. How do I proceed the situation with Apache spark in a distributed manner.

I have tried to create a JavaRDD with a map function which override a call method and converted that to an Dataset[Row] from the two files. Now I’m planning to do a sparkSQL join queries over the datasets. Is this the right approach, anyone can guide me in this, as this’s my first footstep with apache spark.
How do I achieve the parallel processing here?

Comment: Read through "JoinSelection" in [`SparkStrategies.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala)

Comment: Is there any java doc to refer

Comment: Is this approach right @Elliott Frisch?